# Wordpress calendar plugin not showing up on Sundays

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, calendar

This is my first post here and I apologize if I explained too much or disrespected any rule.

There is a calendar plugin ("mk2 plugin" let's call it as it is not a public plugin) which is used to show events from programs (posts) in Wordpress. The only problem is it does NOT show the events when it comes to Sundays.

Every other day it works perfectly and shows the events for the whole week, even shows it for sundays. The calendar shows a week view and shows all the days events for the whole week but when we are on Sundays like today, it shows nothing of any thing.

I believe it has to do with the code at the end of this post because I changed the order in part of it:

```
                    $days = array(
            __("sunday", "mk2"),
            __("monday", "mk2"), 
            __("tuesday", "mk2"), 
            __("wednesday", "mk2"),
            __("thursday", "mk2"),
            __("friday", "mk2"),
            __("saturday", "mk2")
        );
```

and took Sunday to the end and Monday to be first. With that changed, it shows now only Sunday events and not other days which clearly was not the solution as it should show for events for all days (Wordpress start day setting is set to Monday). let me know if I should provide more information!

```
    $schedule_times = array();

    $post = get_post($program_id);

        $days = array(
            __("sunday", "mk2"),
            __("monday", "mk2"), 
            __("tuesday", "mk2"), 
            __("wednesday", "mk2"),
            __("thursday", "mk2"),
            __("friday", "mk2"),
            __("saturday", "mk2")
        );

        foreach($days as $index => $day) {
            $color = mk2_Toolkit::get_post_meta($post->ID, "accent_color", true, "#444444");


        $times = get_post_meta($post->ID, $day . "_time");

        $start_of_week = get_option("start_of_week");

        if($start_of_week == 0) {
            $last_day_of_week = 6;
        }
        else {
            $last_day_of_week = $start_of_week - 1;
        }

    $start = (date('w', strtotime("today")) == 0) ? strtotime("today") : strtotime('last sunday', strtotime("today"));

    if($start_of_week == 0) {
        $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this $day", $start));
    }
    elseif($start_of_week == 1) {
        if($index == 0) {
            $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("next $day", $start));
        }
        else {
            $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this $day", $start));
        }
    }
    elseif($index >= $start_of_week) {
        $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-" . (7-$index) . " day", $start));
    }
    else {
        $day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("this $day", $start));
    }
    if(!empty($times)) {

      foreach($times as $key => $time) {

        list($start_time, $end_time) = explode(",", $time);

        $start_date = "$day $start_time";
        $end_date   = "$day $end_time";

        if($end_date <= $start_date) {
            $end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+24 hours", strtotime($end_date)));
        }


        array_push($schedule_times, array_merge($options, array(
            "id"      => mk2_Service::get_name() . "_" . $post->ID,
            "title"   => $post->post_title,
            "start"   => $start_date,
            "end"     => $end_date,
            "allDay"  => false,
            "color"   => $color,
            "url"     => get_permalink($post->ID)
        )));    
                }
            }
        }

        return $schedule_times;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe the plugin decided to take Sundays off ?

Comment: Then the era they talk about which robots revolt against us has arrived!

Comment: Undo your array modification (replace sunday) and set the following option $start_of_week to 1 instead of (the default) 0, this should change the calendar the way you want.

Comment: Yes, it worked even though I did trial and error as had no clue which start date to change. Here is how I did what you said. Please confirm so hopefully it continues to work properly for other days as it used to. The original format of days had Sunday first on top and Saturday at bottom. I changed it to Monday to be first. When I tried your method, I took Sunday back to the first and Saturday to the end. The only zero I changed to 1 was (date('w', strtotime("today")) == 1). I did NOT change 2x "if($start_of_week == 0)". Is everything right now? By the way,how I choose your reply as the answer?

Comment: Aha, this is a comment so I can't choose a comment as the answer. @axel.michel , could you confirm if in my previous comment I changed as you asked but I was not sure if I was changing the correct 0 to 1. There were other conditional ones which I left untouched. I change (date('w', strtotime("today")) == 0) from 0 to 1 and sunday is on top of the days and saturday is the last or bottom. everything alright? Thank you!

Comment: Leave the complete script unchanged, there must be a option you can set - see the line: get_option("start_of_week"); find it, and set it to 1, and calendar should run.

Comment: sorry but below is where you pointed to, could you exactly tell me which one or paste it with the changed attribute:  $start_of_week = get_option("start_of_week");

      if($start_of_week == 0) {
       $last_day_of_week = 6;
      }
      else {
       $last_day_of_week = $start_of_week - 1;
      }

       $start = (date('w', strtotime("today")) == 0) ? strtotime("today") : strtotime('last sunday', strtotime("today"));

Comment: I left the script untouched and only changed $start = (date('w', strtotime("today")) == 0) to $start = (date('w', strtotime("today")) == 1) and now it shows properly but was it the one you meant? I don't want to have something fixed randomly but rather to it to be your solution!